# passing an additional parameter to JavascriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json

I'm using `JavascriptSerializer` with custom `JavascriptConverter` like this:

```
public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
{
   SomeObjectModel TheObject = obj as SomeObjectModel;
   Dictionary<string, object> OutputJson = new Dictionary<string, object>();

   OutputJson.Add("SomeKey", SomeObjectModel.SomeProperty);

   return OutputJson;
}
```

Now I want to be able to dynamically change `SomeKey` at runtime so I thought of creating a dictionary of keys, passing this dictionary to the serializer, and doing something like this:

```
OutputJson.Add(TheJsonDictionary.SomeKey, SomeObjectModel.SomeProperty);
```

However, when I add a parameter to the function call like this:

```
public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(Dictionary<string, string> TheJsonDictionary, object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
```

I get an error message at compilation. Now I know why I'm getting this error (the abstract method is defined with 2 parameters and I'm passing 3) and I'm wondering how to go around this so that I can pass in a dictionary to encode the keys.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `OutputJson.Add("SomeKey", TheObject.SomeProperty);`?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: That is what is currently outputted however what I want to do is create a dictionary of <strings, strings> and have <SomeKey, "SomeKey"> so that I can write OutputJson.Add(TheJsonDictionary.SomeKey, SomeObjectModel.SomeProperty); Basically, I want the keys to be variables instead of hard-coded into the serializer/deserializer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the only workaround would be to subclass the `JavaScriptSerializer` and reimplement the `Serialize` method to accept an arbitrary `TheJsonDictionary` dictionary:

```
class CustomJavaScriptSerializer : JavaScriptSerializer
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> TheJsonDictionary { get; private set; }

    public string Serialize(object obj, Dictionary<string, string> TheJsonDictionary = null)
    {
        this.TheJsonDictionary = TheJsonDictionary;
        return base.Serialize(obj);
    }
}
```

Now in your custom converter you can cast the serializer object back to `CustomJavaScriptSerializer` and get the custom diectionary of keys:

```
public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
{
    var TheJsonDictionary = (serializer as CustomJavaScriptSerializer).TheJsonDictionary;

    // rest of method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, this is what you need:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //dict.Add("SomeKey", "SomeProperty1");
        dict.Add("SomeKey", "SomeProperty2");
        var myConverter = new MyConverter();
        var serialized = myConverter.Serialize(dict, new SomeObjectModel() { SomeProperty1 = 1, SomeProperty2 = 2 }, new MySerializer());
    }

    class MySerializer : JavaScriptSerializer
    { }

    class MyConverter : JavaScriptConverter
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> _theJsonDictionary;

        public IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(Dictionary<string, string> TheJsonDictionary, object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            _theJsonDictionary = TheJsonDictionary;
            return Serialize(obj, serializer);
        }
        public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            SomeObjectModel TheObject = obj as SomeObjectModel;
            Dictionary<string, object> OutputJson = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var item in _theJsonDictionary.Keys)
            {
                OutputJson.Add(item, TheObject.GetType().GetProperty(_theJsonDictionary[item]).GetValue(TheObject));
            }
            return OutputJson;
        }

        public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            return new object();
        }

        public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
        {
            get { return new[] { typeof(object) }.AsEnumerable(); }
        }
    }

    class SomeObjectModel
    {
        public int SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
        public int SomeProperty2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want "SomeKey" to hard-coded so OutputJson.Add("SomeKey"... is not what I'm looking to do. I want to have the json key to be variable.

Comment: As you can see, I removed the `override` method modifier.

Comment: How about now? I parse the `_theJsonDictionary` and add each of its key / value pairs to the output.

Comment: ok, let me take a look at it and I'll get back to you. Thanks for your answer, it should indeed solve the problem.